# Outlook 2010 group responses

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have two email addresses at work, one is personal and one is for the group of 8. Currently using groupwise we can all respond using the group email, but now on outlook we can only respond from the personal address. How do we make it so that all responses from email to the group address come from the group address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When composing a new mail message, there should be a button labeled 'From' and an indication which of the available accounts the message will be sent from.  Use the From button to select the most appropriate account for your email.

[image]

[Image from MS Outlook Blog](http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-outlook/archive/2009/08/25/multiple-exchange-accounts-in-outlook-2010.aspx)